# login form with php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i don't know where my problem is... i am trying to do a simple sign in form using ajax,jquery and PHP... the problem is that $result always returns false.

i am really new in this hope tou can all help me.

php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $user_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE
    userName = '$user_name' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if($result === true)
        echo $user_name;
    else
        echo 'Error';
}
?>
```

the form it self:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="sign_in.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="sign_in_wrapper">
 <textarea id="user_name"></textarea>
 <textarea id="password"></textarea>
 <button id="sign_in_button">Sign In!</button>
 </div>
 <div id="error"></div>

 <script>
    $('#sign_in_button').click(function () { 
    var user_name = $('textarea#user_name').val();
     var password = $('textarea#password').val();
    signIn(user_name,password);
    });

    function signIn(user_name, password) 
     {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST", 
       url: "sign_in.php",
       data: "user_name="+user_name+"&password="+password,
    success: function(result)
    {   
        if(result = 'Error')
             document.getElementById("error").innerHTML ='user name and password are not match';
        else
             document.getElementById("sign_in_wrapper").innerHTML ='Welcome back '+result;  
    }
})}
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I changed my php code:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['password']))
 {
    $user_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE
    userName = '$user_name' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $result_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); // <-- this is the way to check the result

     if($result_rows)
    // OK
         echo $user_name;
     else
    // Bad login
         echo 'Error';
}
?>
```

Now Im gettning a different Error:
"Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Project\sign_in.php on line 10"

Line 10 is: $result_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

and thank you all for your quick answers!

Comment: Why did you transition to javaScript functions, `document.getElementById("error")` vs `$('#error')`

Comment: $result = mysql_query($sql); Please use mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_num_rows to get the rows returned because mysql_query will be a resource id if the query is executed successfully even if the username and password is wrong

Comment: Also, are your 'password' and 'user_name' fields really `textarea`s and not `input`s with type `text` and `password`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

will always return true (**Resource#** in your case if the SQL query is OK). There is no need to have such row with checked username/password.

You have to:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$result_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); // <-- this is the way to check the result

    if($result_rows)
        // OK
        echo $user_name;
    else
        // Bad login
        echo 'Error';
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is still doesn not working. Im getting the next error: "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Project\sign_in.php on line 10" do you know why is that?

Comment: I suppose that is because 'password' is mysql function and is bad idea to be used for column name. Try this: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `userName` = '$user_name' AND `password` = '$password'";

Comment: Sorry, I writted in wrong way. Must be: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `userName` = '$user_name' AND `password` = '$password'";` Have in mind that I used **``password``** symbols(`) across field name - this is a good practice to stay away from such problems, but be careful when naming your columns.

Comment: Thanck you. helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result === true)
```

The result will never be `true`. It will either be `FALSE` or a [resource](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).

Use `if ($result)` instead and then test ([with `mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) or (preferably) a modern equivalent) how many rows you got back (since a successful query with no matching rows will give you a result).

Comment: even if the SQL does not return any row and the query is executed successfully in mysql, mysql_query will return resource id. so it will be true for wrong credentials as well.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha — That's why I said you should also test with `mysql_num_rows`.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha — Before your comment actually (but probably after you started typing it).

Comment: Please do an edit for the answer, i am not able to upvote it :). Please do any small edit.

Answer (score 0):

check your line here

```
 data: "user_name="+user_name+"&password="+password,
```

the proper format would be

```
data: {user_name:user_name,password:password},
```

also here

```
if(result = 'Error')
             document.getElementById("error").innerHTML ='user name and password are not match';
        else
             document.getElementById("sign_in_wrapper").innerHTML ='Welcome back '+result;
```

your assigning in your if else statement to your result

try changing `result == 'Error'`

and yeah change this also

```
if($result === true) 
        echo $user_name;
    else
        echo 'Error';
```

with

```
if ($result) {
   echo $user_name;
}else {
   echo 'Error';
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. just one question: why do I need to change- data: "user_name="+user_name+"&password="+password, TO data: {user_name:user_name,password:password}, ?

Comment: it will just do fine with your old code, however it is more likely readable and a standard way in passing data into your ajax request. (: